# Using async / await with dynamic import() for ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise, modules

I am experimenting with the best way to standardise my dynamic `import()` expressions when importing javascript modules.

`import()` returns a promise, so, to handle the asynchronous steps after the`import()` expression, I can use either:

- `.then()` syntax; or
- `async` / `await` syntax

Whilst I am quite familiar with the older `XHR2` approach and somewhat familiar with ES2015 `.then()` syntax, I am less familiar with `async` / `await` syntax.

I understand that I can only use `await` *inside* a function which has been declared or assigned with `async`.

But I am trying to understand why **Approach 1** works.

**Approach 1:**

```
(async () => {

  let myImportedModule = await import('/path/to/my-module.js');

  myImportedModule.myFunction1();
  myImportedModule.myFunction2();

})();
```

But **Approach 2** does not.

**Approach 2:**

```
(async () => {

  await import('/path/to/my-module.js');

  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();

})();
```

---

**Additional Notes:**

Clearly I have something wrong, but I thought **Approach 2** would be the `async` / `await` equivalent of *this* snippet (using `.then()` syntax):

```
import('/path/to/my-module.js')

  .then((myImportedModule) => {

    myImportedModule.myFunction1();
    myImportedModule.myFunction2();

  });
```

but that it would enable me to access `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` directly, without needing to give a name to the resolved `Promise`.

Comment: It's the opposite. Approach 1 is the equivalent of the `then` version. Otherwise the meaning would be completely different. To understand this, think about how names are resolved and how they can be shadowed.

Comment: Thanks, @AluanHaddad. I'm just trying to find a way to avoid returning the functions as properties of a named object. Whatever syntax I try, that's what they keep coming back as. The only way I have succeeded in extracting the properties from the object is by deploying `for (let entry of Object.entries(moduleTest)) {window[entry[0]] = entry[1];}` - but then I end up with the functions at `global` scope and I definitely don't want that. I just want them as standalone functions at the scope of the `module` they have been `imported` into.

Comment: But that's not how modules work in general. Maybe you want a destructuring assignment (`const {f, g} = await import(...);`)? If you want them at module scope, that's highly problematic.

Comment: You may also be interested in https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await, which you can start using now if you use TypeScript or Babel.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, @AluanHaddad. This is a key statement: _"But that's not how modules work in general."_ I've reconciled myself to importing an object with properties, rather than individual variables whenever I use dynamic `import()`.

Comment: Glad to be of service. I think the ergonomics don't bother me as much since I usually just `export default expression`, a habit I got into because of loader-interop issues and then became enamored of. I fully understand why many prefer to export multiple bindings though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Approach 2** does not work because [accoring to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Description):

```
import '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Is how you `import` a module for **Import a module for its side effects only**

> Import an entire module for side effects only, without importing anything. This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values.

So, `await import('/path/to/my-module.js');` won't actually import your `myfunction1` and `myFunction2` for you to use them, however, if you put an IIFE in there, it will be called.

If you don't want to use long names to call your function, you can destructure them :

```
(async () => {

  const { myFunction1, myFunction2 } = await import('/path/to/my-module.js');

  myFunction1();
  myFunction2();

})();
```

Or, call them in `my-module.js` and just import it and they will get called.

See the answers here for [es6 import for side effects meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127479/es6-import-for-side-effects-meaning).

Answer (score 0):

for some reason this wasn't working for me:

```
const {capitalize} = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */'lodash').default
```

but this *is*:

```js
const {capitalize} = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */'lodash')
    .then(module=>module?.default);
```

note: i'm using Webpack's experimental [topLevelAwait](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/) option set to `true`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), though only if you have **working code**. This statement would be appropriate as a  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), though you will need to earn 50 reputation points first...

Comment: The first one does not work because `.default` is on the promise. This works: `(await import(/* webpackChunkName: "lodash" */'lodash')).default`